# Laravel - getting a value from a relationship's attributes as an attribute of the current model

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 models: Car and Condition

Car and Condition have a 1 to 1 polymorphic relationship. Condition gets joined onto Car:

```
class Car extends Model 
{
    // ...

    public function condition()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Condition::class, 'carable');
    }
}

class Condition extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function carable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo()
    }
}
```

This returns the following structure:

```
{ // car
    "id": 1,
    "condition": {
        "age": "1 year",
        "serviced": "yes"
    }
}
```

I want to also return the `age` attribute on the car's level, i.e.

```
{ // car
    "id": 1,
    "age": "1 year",
    "condition": {
        "age": "1 year",
        "serviced": "yes"
    }
}
```

I want to do this by getting the condition->age attribute inside the car model. I've tried setting up the following in the Car class:

```
protected $appends = ["age"];
protected function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return $this->getFinancialAttribute()->getAgeAttribute();
}
```

as well as some other variations thereof, with no success. Is there any way for me to do this elegantly?

Comment: @dparoli it was a typo, updating now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add this code to your `Car` model:

```php
protected $appends = ['age'];
protected function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return $this->condition->age;
}
```

But be sure to [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `condition` with your `Car` model to avoid the N + 1 query problem.

```php
$cars = Car::with('condition')->get();
```

In your case you can eager load **by default** adding this line to your `Car` model:

```php
protected $with = ['condition'];
```

BTW your relationship on the `Car` model should be like this:

```php
public function condition()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Condition::class, 'carable');
}
```

Comment: Well that's hella frustrating - I was sure I'd done this correctly but I undid my changes and followed yours step by step and they worked, thank you! Regarding the relations - I just typed those out quickly (company policy to rename class names etc when asking on here and elsewhere) so it was just a type, the relationship is already working fine, but will update my original post!

Comment: Yes I understood after commenting that was only a typo because you posted the right json result. That's why I answered anyway.